# How to run Google Keep as an App in Windows

Tags: windows, shortcut, kiosk

How does one run Google Keep or other websites like an app or kiosk on a Windows PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I figured this out and nobody seems to of had a response, I made my own question and answered it. Credit to [OurCodeWorld](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1187/how-to-open-a-url-in-google-chrome-with-a-specific-window-size-using-the-command-line-in-windows-10) for helping figure out some of the fine tuning. He had a --chrome-frame flag, but I believe that is [depreciated](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started), so I am looking into it. But it seems to work fine without it

TLDR: Create a shortcut to chrome and add `--app=` this to the end of it. like this `--app=https://keep.google.com/u/0/`.

Now if you want it to have a specific size window? Well, you will have to add `--window-size=WIDTH,LENGTH`. But... Chrome saves the size of the last window closed, which If you use Chrome as a browser, this will change frequently. To solve this, we create a separate user-data directory `--user-data-dir="C:\ExampleDir"`. This folder is around 50mb of who knows what...

So the whole thing put together, like this.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="%localappdata%\GoogleKeep\User Data" --window-size=950,1000 --app=https://keep.google.com/u/0/
```